# Merging two NGINX Rewrite rules in one

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

how could i merge those two rules in a single one for NGINX?

```
rewrite ^/myfolder/(.*)  http://myfolder.example.com permanent;
rewrite ^/myfolder       http://myfolder.example.com permanent;
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to extend your regex pattern in the first rule to optionally accept the last slash:

```
rewrite ^/myfolder(/?(.*))  http://myfolder.example.com permanent;
```

Comment: Get rid of all the brackets in there. You're not capturing anything. It will still work and saves pcre /nginx some space.